# generate all permutations in order without using excessive memory

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I got an interview question that I can't seem to figure out: Given an array of intergers. Write a program to print all the permutations of the numbers in the array. The output should be sorted in a decreasing order. For example for the array { 12, 4, 66, 8, 9}, the output should be:

9866412

9866124

9846612

....

....

1246689

One obvious solution is to permute then sort but that will take n! memory. I'm looking for something that will take polynomial memory.

I tried writing recursive solution that involved generating the permutations starting from the largest lexicographical numbers:

```
def compare(x,y):
    for i in range(max(len(x), len(y))):
        if len(x) <= i:
            return compare(x[0], y[i])
        elif len(y) <= i:
            return compare(x[i], y[0])
        elif x[i] < y[i]:
            return -1
        elif x[i] > y[i]:
            return 1
    return 0

def print_all_permutations(so_far, num_lst):
    if not num_lst:
        print so_far
    for i in range(len(num_lst)):
        cur = num_lst.pop(i)
        print_all_permutations(so_far + [str(cur)], num_lst)
        num_lst.insert(i, cur)

input_arr = sorted([str(x) for x in [3,31,0]], cmp = compare, reverse=True)
```

But this fails for cases like:

```
['3', '31', '0']
3310
3031
error 3130(['31', '3', '0']) is greater than ['3', '0', '31'](3031)
3130
3103
331
313
```

Comment: Define "without using excessive memory". Is it required to be `O(1)`? If so - the `soFar` is also not premitted (it is `O(n)`) and also using recursion is not allowed, since the stack requires `O(n)` memory as well.

Comment: I'm looking for something at most polynomial.

Comment: n items have n! combination. How do expect to achieve less than that ?

Comment: Are you talking about time complexity or space complexity ?

Comment: @ Rsh, space complexity. Time complexity will be at least n! as you said.

Comment: Have a look at C++ library source, in particular next_permutation().  Given a permutation, it is possible to derive the lexicographically following permutation, assuming there is one.

Comment: @rossum: from the example, it seems that the required order is different.  The order is based on taking the individual digits of the numbers and putting them together into a single number.

Comment: @Vaughn Cato: The ordering complicates the ordering/comparison of the elements of the array, but the problem can still be solved by stepping from one arrangement to the next.  You could just permute an easy array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and map from that to the actual array.

Comment: @rossum: I thought about that, but the results don't come out the same when there are duplicate digits.  For example, {1,22,3} -> {3,2,2,1} -> 3221 3212 3221 3212 3122 3122 ...  The initial permutation results don't come out numerically sorted.

Comment: @rossum: I've added an answer based on that idea.  Let me know if that matches what you were thinking.

Answer (score 2):

It appears this can be solved by generating the permutations of the digits in order without duplicates, and then for each permuation of digits finding all the matching values.  Here's an example in python:

```
def reversed_numerically_ordered_permutations(values):
  def permute(digits,prefix):
    assert type(digits) is str
    if len(digits)==0:
      match(prefix,values,[])
    last_digit=None
    for i in range(len(digits)):
      if digits[i]!=last_digit:
        permute(digits[0:i]+digits[i+1:],prefix+digits[i])
        last_digit=digits[i]

  def match(x,values,prefix):
    assert type(x) is str
    if len(x)==0 and len(values)==0:
      print prefix
    for i in range(len(values)):
      value=values[i]
      value_str=str(value)
      if x.startswith(value_str):
        match(x[len(value_str):],values[0:i]+values[i+1:],prefix+[value])

  digits=sorted(''.join(str(x) for x in values),reverse=True)
  digits=''.join(digits)
  permute(digits,'')

reversed_numerically_ordered_permutations([3,31,0])
```

Output:

```
[3, 31, 0]
[31, 3, 0]
[31, 0, 3]
[3, 0, 31]
[0, 3, 31]
[0, 31, 3]
```

However, this could be extremely inefficient in some cases.

Comment: That looks like what I was thinking, though my Python isn't good.  Permute an easy array and map to the real array.

Comment: This produces the correct results and is within my memory bounds. However, as you mentioned, the running time is a little worse than n!. For every permutation you check n numbers. I believe the runtime here is actually O(D!*N) where D is the number of _digits_. IE: I can make the runtime slower by adding an arbitrarily large number like [3333333333333333333333333333333, 31, 0]. Nevertheless, it's still better than what I came up with haha

Comment: @citysushi: I think it is possible to do better.  I've experimented with a solution where any time the ordering is unclear (strings of different lengths that have the same prefix), two permutation generators are created and a merging generator makes sure the combined results come out in the correct order.  It looks promising.